# C# ListBox syncing with each other

Tags: c#, listboxitems

I am trying to make a program that has 3 listBoxes an I need to alphabetize 1 of them but the and the other 2 listboxes info needs to still match the first listBox. As of now I don't have any code for that to show, but I do have my add item code to give a general idea of what I am looking for.

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (itemTextBox.Text == "")
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter an item to add");
    else
    groceryListBox.Items.Add(itemTextBox.Text);
    itemTextBox.Clear();
    countTextBox.Text = groceryListBox.Items.Count.ToString();

    //if (quanityListBox.Text == "")
    //    MessageBox.Show("Please enter an item to add");
    //else
        quanityListBox.Items.Add(quanityTextBox.Text);
    quanityTextBox.Clear();
   // countTextBox.Text = quanityListBox.Items.Count.ToString();

    //if (priceListBox.Text == "")
    //    MessageBox.Show("Please enter an item to add");
    //else
        priceListBox.Items.Add(priceTextBox.Text);
    priceTextBox.Clear();
    //countTextBox.Text = priceListBox.Items.Count.ToString();
    itemTextBox.Focus();
}


private void removeSingleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (groceryListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            while(groceryListBox.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
            {
                groceryListBox.Items.Remove(groceryListBox.SelectedItems[0]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select an item(s) to remove");
        }
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Settings.Default["List1"] = groceryListBox.Items.ToString();
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groceryListBox.Text = Settings.Default["List1"].ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groceryListBox.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groceryListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
        for (int i = groceryListBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (groceryListBox.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Equals(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
                groceryListBox.SetSelected(i, true);
    }

    private void colorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groceryListBox.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    }

    private void containsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            groceryListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
            for (int i = groceryListBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (groceryListBox.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
                    groceryListBox.SetSelected(i, true);
        }
    }

    private void startsWithToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            groceryListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
            for (int i = groceryListBox.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (groceryListBox.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
                    groceryListBox.SetSelected(i, true);
        }
    }

    private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editTextBox.Text = groceryListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editTextBox.Paste();
    }

    private void toolsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (editTextBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an item to add");
        else
            groceryListBox.Items[groceryListBox.SelectedIndex] = editTextBox.Text;
        editTextBox.Clear();
        countTextBox.Text = groceryListBox.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit.... I figured out how to post screenshot....

[At least they allow me a link for now, I guess until my reputation goes up. :-)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Uk7.png)

This is what I want it to do, if I add an item to the list with quantity and price, and I have multiple items in the list I still want the quantity and price to match that item across from it.

This might help too.....
[With the items matching the price and quantity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xniGg.png)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I want to sync all 3 listboxes, say I want to alphabetize 1 list and the others should follow the first. I have 3 listBox side by side making different columns, if I add it works, but if I remove it only takes the 1 away and everything is mis-aligned, 2 of the listBoxes quantity and prices so I can't put them in alphabetized, besides they would not line up with the item in which they belong. God I hope I make sense. :-)

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a primary key.  When the item is selected or what not in the first list, save the primary key, then you can iterate through the other two lists and find the changed item via that key.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you're looking for an easy way to show the same info between multiple ListBoxs?  If so you could try the following:

```
    private List<string> testList = new List<string>();

    private void BindTestListData()
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = testList;

        listBox2.DataSource = null;
        listBox2.DataSource = testList;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputTextBox.Text))
        {
            testList.Add(InputTextBox.Text);
            InputTextBox.Clear();
            BindTestListData();
        }
    }
```

Feed all your text from your text box into a list instead of adding it directly to the ListBox.  Then bind the list to the datasource of your ListBox.

**EDIT**

Scratch what I had before.  I think I better understand your problem now.  try something like this:

```
    private struct Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    private void BindTestListData()
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.DataSource = items;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

        listBox2.DataSource = null;
        listBox2.DataSource = items;
        listBox2.DisplayMember = "Quantity";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputTextBox.Text))
        {
            Item newItem = new Item()
            {
                Name = InputTextBox.Text,
                Quantity = "1",
                Price = "$10"
            };
            items.Add(newItem);
            InputTextBox.Clear();
            BindTestListData();
        }
    }
```

Obviously, the numbers in the button1_click() method are just place holders, but something like this should work.

Comment: That looks like it could work, I am how ever using settings to save the list, I am new to stackoverflow so I don't know how to add screen shots.

Comment: No need for a screenshot.  Just copy and paste the code into the comment window.